# getting error when starting xampp with error missing job name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, xampp

I installed xampp in ubuntu 12.04 and everything is ok but when i am trying start it from terminal i get this error:

```
start: missing job name
try 'start --help' for more information.
```

`JOB is the name of the job that is to be started, this may be followed by zero
or more environment variables to be defined in the new job.` This is the information which i got from help but is my first experience with linux. all tutorials on the web tells that all the things that i need to do is just enter `start`... 
What to do?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you follow this guide: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#378
and run command:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Or, you run some other command?(in question is not specified what you have executed). If so, most likely something is not correctly installed...
Also you should provide xampp version, how the software was installed (rpm, compiled,....)

Comment: OMG I just changed directory to /opt/lampp/ and entered `start` the whole mistake... I corrected to `sudo /opt/lampp/lamp start`... bad habit from windows, my mistake, Thanks @xhudik

Comment: yep, stupid things are happening to everyone :). greeting to afganistan, once when there will be less violence, I'd like to visit your country ...

Comment: :* but there is nothing fun here to see except disappointment :D

Comment: is it really that bad and no light at the end of tunnel? Was it better in past? write me: xhudik@gmail.com